# Is the reverse action of each action included in the generators for that group?

Tags: group-theory

My apologies if this is unclear, I've just started reading "Visual Group Theory" and I just wanted to make sure of this as early as possible!
So say there's a situation which can be considered as a "group", and therefore there's a unchanging list of actions, each of which has a reverse - are these reverse actions to be included in the "generators" for that group?

Comment: If an element generates the group, then so does its inverse - is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I think that is!

Comment: So the reverse action is counted as a generator too. But in the case of a Rubik's cube, the action "turn 90 degrees right" can generate it's own inverse, so then there's no need. Is that correct?

Comment: Sort of - an element might not necessarily generate its own inverse, but its inverse is certainly generated by some combination of operations. If the group is finite then an element will eventually generate its own inverse, though. Consider that an exercise!